# Implement UIToolBar so it acts like a UITabBar and UIToolBar at the same time

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, cocoa-design-patterns

I have an interesting problem. I have an app that I'm developing that involves photos so screen space is at a premium. Also, using disappearing and reappearing nav / tool bar controllers (like in the camera app) doesn't make sense for me. In a perfect world, I'd use a UITabBar to switch between the 4 main navigational view controllers that my program implements, however I also am going to need space for a toolbar right on top of the tab bar most of the time. These two components take up too much space between the two of them so I need a way to save some space.

That's where I came up with the idea of using a toolbar to implement the functionality of both the TabBar and ToolBar. On the left side of the ToolBar would be the 4 buttons that allow access to my 4 main navigational view controllers. The one that is currently on the window would have it's button depressed. Then there would be a divider, and on the right side of the tool bar would be buttons specific to whatever view is currently on the window.

Anyhow, I'm just wondering if anyone has any clever ideas on how they'd implement this?

Answer (score 0):

wat do u mean by left and right of toolbar??? adding a tab bar will not affect ur view size. when adding a toolbar, well yes it does affect ur view size.

my idea wolud be add a toolbar to the top of ur view and u can make it visible only when the user taps on the screen. until then keep the toolbar hidden. when the user clicks for the second time on the screen hide ur toolbar. this way u can have the whole view for ur pics and also have a toolbar for giving options.

Comment: I meant the left portion of the toolbar would be for buttons to navigate to other views, and the right portion would be for buttons associated with the current view. Not sure what you mean a tabbar won't affect view size, but a toolbar will? Tabbar will take up 49 pixels at the bottom of screen. Thanks for the idea, but having the disappearing toolbar won't work for me, I need mine to be visible.